# Combinatorial problem: Directed Acyclic Graph

Tags: graph-theory

How many unique landscapes exist in 5D DAG (directed acyclic graph)? There are $2^5$ points (eg: 00000, 00001, ... 11111) and $(2^5)!$ combinations.

The problem is a combinatorial problem. It should be fun and interesting, and I am interested in discussing the solution here as well.

It is classifying all distinct 5 dimensional landscapes. A landscape in 5-space is an assignment of edge direction to each edge between vertices such that a directed acyclic graph is formed (DAG).

Classification might include the number of peaks, basins, or a metric like that.

There are $(2^5)! $ combinations so obviously iterating through each combination and testing if it is a new landscape or an orientation of an old one won't work.

For example in the 2D case, there are $(2^2)!$ permutations  = $24$. This 24 is made up of 3 landscapes. There are 8 orientations of each one.

I am reluctant to draw a picture at first, because maybe the way you visualize it will help you find a solution.

Comment: Are you seeking the number of [acyclic orientations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acyclic_orientation) of the 5D hypercube?  This is given by the [Tutte polynomial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tutte_polynomial) evaluated at $(2,0)$.  It might be hard to compute the Tutte polynomial of this graph though.

Comment: Maybe. I am looking for unique orientations (ie: relabel the graph, is the structure the same as an already found structure?)

Answer (score 5):

This is really only a partial answer. What I think you are asking for is a calculation of the number of non-isomorphic acyclic orientations of the hypercube $Q_5$ where two orientations are isomorphic if there is an automorphism of $Q_5$ taking one to the other.

This can be done as an (almost) straightforward application of Burnside's Lemma as described by Peter Cameron [in these notes](http://www.maths.qmul.ac.uk/~pjc/csgnotes/countcols.pdf).

First, as Rebecca suggested, you should recall the [pretty amazing result of Stanley](http://www-math.mit.edu/~rstan/pubs/pubfiles/18.pdf) that if $\chi_G(x)$ denotes the [chromatic polynomial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chromatic_polynomial) of a graph $G$ on $n$ vertices, then $(-1)^n\chi_G(-1)$ is equal to the number of acyclic orientations of $G$.

Now, let $G$ be a graph and let $Aut(G)$ be its automorphism group. If $\sigma\in Aut(G)$, let $G/\sigma$ be the graph obtained by identifying the vertices in the orbits (i.e., cycles) of $\sigma$. This graph may contains loops and multiedges but for the statements below, multiedges may safely be replaced by a single edge.

> *Theorem*: The number of non-isomorphic acyclic orientations that can be placed on $G$ is equal to $$\frac{1}{|Aut(G)|} \sum_{\sigma\in Aut(G)} (-1)^{sgn(\sigma)}\chi_{G/\sigma}(-1).$$

Note that if $G/\sigma$ has a loop, then $\chi_{G/\sigma}(x)=0$.

As for the hypercube graph $Q_n$, $Aut(Q_n)$ is isomorphic to the [hyperoctohedral group](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperoctahedral_group), so in principle the above formula can be evaluated by anyone determined enough to do so. But even for $n=5$, Maple has trouble finding the chromatic polynomial of $Q_5$ using the basic command, and I'm not expert enough to coax an answer from it. Perhaps someone else can make that calculation.

On the other hand, the case $n=2$ is easy enough that I will do it here to illustrate the theorem. In this case, if we label the vertices of $Q_2$ in cyclic order as $1,2,3,4$, then $$Aut(Q_2)=\{(1),(1\,2\,3\,4), (1\,3)(2\, 4), (1\,4\,3\,2),(2\,4),(1\,2)(3\,4),(1\,3),(1\,4)(2\,3)\}.$$

But we really only need consider $\sigma\in\{(1),(1\,3)(2\, 4), (2\,4),(1\,3)\}$ since the other $\sigma$ are such that $G/\sigma$ has loops.

For $\sigma=(1)$, $G/\sigma=G$. The chromatic polynomial of the $4$-cycle is $(x-1)^4+(x-1)$.

For $\sigma=(1\,3)(2\,4)$, $G/\sigma$ is isomorphic to a path on $2$ vertices and so $$\chi_{G/\sigma}(x)=x(x-1).$$

For $\sigma=(1\,3)$ or $(2\,4)$, $G/\sigma$ is isomorphic to a path on $3$ vertices and so $$\chi_{G/\sigma}(x)=x(x-1)^2.$$

Applying the theorem gives that the number of non-isomorphic acycle orientations of $Q_2$ is obtained by plugging in $x=-1$ into $$\frac{1}{8}\left( (x-1)^4+(x-1) + x(x-1)- x(x-1)^2 - x(x-1)^2\right),$$ which, as you already know, is equal to $3$.

**Added:** A lower bound for $Q_5$ can be obtained using results found in a paper of [Kahale and Schulman](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.54.6626&rep=rep1&type=pdf). Their Theorem 6 shows that $$(-1)^n\chi_G(-1)\geq \prod_{v\in V(G)} (deg(v)+1)!^{\frac{1}{\deg(v)+1}}.$$

Since $Q_5$ has 32 vertices, is $5$-regular and $|Aut(Q_5)|= 5!(2^5)$, we see that there are at least $$\left\lceil\frac{6!^{\frac{32}{6}}}{5!(2^5)}\right\rceil = 451, 622, 346, 888 $$ non-isomorphic acyclic orientations. I have no idea how close that is to the exact number, but do you really need many more?

Comment: Wow great answer! I have been working through it. I really appreciate it. I have a question I have been wondering about: How does the edge coloring or vertex theorems relate to my edge direction problem? Do I have one color for every vertice? If I color them by # of incoming and # of outgoing edges, I run into conflicts where two colors are next to each other. I could color the edge by whether it is incoming or outgoing, but how do I decide that? I suppose I could do it by the # of bits since one vertice's name will always have a higher number of bits associated with it

Comment: Ah I see the edge coloring's next description is no two vertices have an edge of the same color. So the method I proposed won't work. Any idea how to apply either the vertex or edge coloring?

Comment: It's a bit early where I am but I'm not sure what you're asking? Are you looking for a method to go for a vertex or edge coloring to a directed acyclic orientation?

Comment: Yes! I think so

Comment: Hmm ok. I'm not sure offhand but it's an interesting question and I'll think about it when I get to work in a few hours.

Comment: Casteels, where did you get the "Now, let G be a graph ..." and Theorem from? I don't see that in Stanley's paper

Comment: No it's in Peter Cameron's notes, at the end.

Comment: As in Stanley's paper, suppose you have a proper *vertex* colouring of $G=(V,E)$ using colours $\{1,2,\ldots, k\}$, i.e., you have a map $c\colon V \to\{1,2,\ldots, k\}$ satisfying $c(v)\neq c(w)$ whenever $(v,w)\in E$. 

From $c$ you can definte an orientation by directing the edge $(v,w)$ from $v$ to $w$ if $c(v)>c(w)$, and from $w$ to $v$ otherwise. 

This orientation is acyclic since if $v_0\to v_1\to \cdots \to v_k=v_0$ is a directed cycle then the colouring would satisfy $c(v_0)>c(v_1)>\cdots> c(v_k)=c(v_0)$ which is plainly impossible.

Comment: I thought the colouring theorem was about adjacent colours not touching, and your comment cleared up how to connect the ideas for me. I had to read a couple times to get it. Thanks ^_^

Comment: Isn't the chromatic polynomial for $Q_5$ equal $x\ (x-1)^5\ (x-2)^{10} \ (x-3)^{10} \ (x-4)^5\ (x-5)$ ?http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x+%28x-1%29%5E5+%28x-2%29%5E10+%28x-3%29%5E10+%28x-4%29%5E5+%28x-5%29

Comment: @seteropere no that can't be correct since it evaluates to zero when $x=2$, but should evaluate to a positive number since $Q_5$ is bipartite.